# how to join between two databases in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having a problem joining these two databases using codeigniter, I tried it using mysql and it worked.

can someone can convert it to codeigniter

This is my code

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ex.extime), '%Y-%m-%d') as `export_report`, u.username as `Username`, ex.qdesc as `Search_Performed`,
                 ex.to as `Number_of_records_exported`, ex.format as `Format`
                 FROM cone.users u
                 INNER JOIN igdata.export_status as ex
                 ON u.id = ex.uid
                 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ex.extime), '%Y-%m-%d') = '{$dateToday}'
                 ORDER BY u.username ASC
```

I also put this in my constructor

```
private $cone_read;
private $ixdata;

function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();

    $this->cone_read = $this->load->database('cone_read', TRUE);
    $this->ixdata = $this->load->database('cone_us', TRUE);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
        $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ex.extime), '%Y-%m-%d') as export_report, u.username as Username, ex.qdesc as Search_Performed, ex.to as Number_of_records_exported, ex.format as Format");    
        $this->db->from('cone.users u');
        $this->db->join('igdata.export_status as ex', 'u.id = ex.uid');
        $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ex.extime), '%Y-%m-%d') = '$dateToday'");
        $this->db->order_by("u.username", "asc");
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Danilo Bustos, It worked like a charm :) This is what I need.